# Python does not find a module on "import" (minimal project, no external imports)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a strange error here. Python is unable to import a module, even though I clearly see that it's there. It's also not a complicated setting with many paths, but just a small project.

**I run `test.py`. It imports module `stencils`. During loading, `stencils/__init.py__` is called. This file is unable to find module `Stencil` which is `stencils/Stencil.py`.**

Furthermore:

- Run `stencils/__init__.py` directly: Works.
- Run `stencils/Abc.py`: Works.
- **Run `test.py` : Gives error:**

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/mi/stencilcodegen/test.py", line 1, in <module>
> import stencils   File "/Users/mi/stencilcodegen/stencils/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
> import Stencil ImportError: No module named 'Stencil'
> ```

**__init__.py:**

```
import Stencil
import Abc
```

**Abc.py:**

```
import Stencil
stencil = Stencil.Stencil
```

**Stencil.py:** (Probably irrelevant, since it does not find the module at all.)

```
class Stencil:
    def __init__(self):
        a = 1;
```

**test.py:**

```
import stencils
a = stencil.Stencil
```

**Directory screenshot (PyCharm)**

[image]

Comment: shouldn't it be stencils.Stencil ?

Comment: There might be follow-up errors but the current problem is that it DOES find and call `stencils/__init.py__` but this file DOES NOT find a module named `Stencil`.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar question, and I found the solution just by coincidence.

Your `test.py` file is the 'root', so when you use any code there you will have to see the hieracy from this perspective. You must import in the subfolder files like this:

in __init_.py for example:

```
import stencils.Stencil as Stencil
import stencils.Abc as Abc
```

Since you are importing the modules and functions and whatever is in your folder `stencils`, you must still give a clear path to the place where the function or whatever is stored. Sorry for my bad expressions, I'm german.

Comment: Renaming without actually renaming is an unnecessary repetition of names: `from stencils import Abc, Stencil`.